# Facebook won't accept URL of our website in the About section of our Facebook page?

Tags: facebook, debugging, standards

We are a legitimate company with an established website, but when I go to enter our website (www.wildfibres.co.uk) into the site field in the About section on our Facebook page, it responds with the error message: "The website URL you provided is invalid. Please enter a correct URL and try again." This problem has only occurred in the last few months.

How do I get Facebook to re-accept our website?

Facebook debugger won't run because it says our site doesn't meet Community Standards. This is a craft site which supports hand crafters and there is no way that it breaches any legitimate standards.

Comment: There isn’t much you can do, expect fill out the “let us know” form the debug tool links to. (But Facebook probably doesn’t get active based on a single report, so perhaps have a couple of friends fill it out, too – maybe stretched out over a couple of days, so it doesn’t get classified as spam.)

Comment: Thanks misorude. I'll try that.

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?